# -аку чи -аці в місцевому відмінку

Tags: відмінювання

Як правильно написати: "на хімфаку" чи "на хімфаці"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дещо додам невизначеності в порівнянні з іншою відповідю…

[«Український правопис» 2019 у § 86 каже](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/%202019.pdf#page=94), що:

- «іменники чол. роду (переважно **безсуфіксні**) — назви неістот» мають **закінчення *-і***: «в а́кті, в ду́сі, у комп’ю́тері, у байра́ці, у бе́резі, у ґру́нті, у декре́ті, у телефо́ні, на ду́бі, на мі́сяці, на по́версі, на поро́зі, на столі́, на язиці́́́́, по асфа́льті, по фунда́менті, при дні, при столі́, при хара́ктері»;
- «іменники чол. та середн. роду твердої групи **із суфіксами *-к-, -ак-, -ик-, -ок-, -к(о)*** — назви неістот» мають **закінчення *-у***: «у ставку́; у горще́чку, у місте́чку; у буди́нку, у гуртку́; у ві́йську; на держаку́, на літаку́, на мішку́; на до́щику, на лі́жку, на яє́чку; по гори́щу, по узбі́чч́ю; при ба́теньку, при підраху́нку. Наявні також і варіантні форми з -ові: на/по/при/у буди́нкові, на/по/при/у держако́ві, на/по/при/у літако́ві, на/по/при/у лі́жкові та ін.».

У слові *хімфак* (*біофак*, *фізфак*, *філфак* тощо) *-ак-* очевидно не є суфіксом, а є частиною кореня (адже *-фак* тут — це *факультет*) — тобто **згідно з «Правописом», якщо слідувати йому буквально, має бути *на хімфаці***. (А як же словник? А в тому словнику, при всій повазі до нього, [іноді трапляються помилки](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B8_online#%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96_%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%97_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8).)

Водночас я не виключаю того, що такі слова (де *-ак* — частина кореня) можуть із плином часу уподібнюватися словам, де *-ак* — справжній суфікс (також я не виключаю того, що формулювання в «Правописі» могло бути неточним). Тож теоретично може бути, що написання ***на хімфаку***, хай навіть і не слідує формально букві «Правопису», **не суперечить його духу**.

А як щодо реального вжитку? У «Генеральному регіонально анотованому корпусі української мови» версії 16 ***на *фаці*** ([228 разів](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac16&tab=advanced&queryselector=cql&cql=%22(?i)%D0%BD%D0%B0%22%20%22(?i).*%D1%84%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%22&showresults=1)) **трапляється приблизно втричі частіше за *на *факу*** ([80 разів](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac16&tab=advanced&queryselector=cql&cql=%22(?i)%D0%BD%D0%B0%22%20%22(?i).*%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%22&showresults=1)). Також можна помітити, що *на роб(іт)фаці* у 1920-х писали письменники розстріляного відродження Василь Воруський, Володимир Ярошенко, Григорій Епік (а перше *на робітфаку* у ГРАК-16 датоване 1960-ми роками, хоча [поза ГРАКом є й давніше трапляння](https://google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%22&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A%2Ccd_max%3A1930)). Загалом картина така:
[image]

Висновок. Принаймні я не бачу підстав вважати варіант *на хімфаці* помилкою. Можливо, коректними є обидва варіанти.

P.S.: «Словники України online» (a.k.a. словник УЛІФ) не лише *хімфак*, а й решту слів на *-фак* (*біофак, робфак, робітфак, фізфак, філфак*) дає із суфіксом *-у*. Водночас подібне слово *барак* (де *-ак* — теж частина кореня) дає з варіативним закінченням: *на/у бара́ці, бара́ку*.

Answer (score 2):

УЛІФ за *хімфаку*, але, здається, є й інші думки.

[image]

Як зауважив у своєму дописі Sasha, можуть бути помилки:

> За свідченням директора фонду, доктора технічних наук, академіка НАН України В. А. Широкова, лексикографічна система створювалася в напівавтоматичному режимі й не виключає помилок:
>
> > Фахівці Фонду змоделювали в комп'ютерному форматі правила словозміни. Кожна лексема відноситься до певного парадигматичного словозмінного класу, вся лексика розбита на ці класи, й для кожного з них виписано правило словозміни, алгоритм, програму. Система ж, базуючись на вихідних формах, самостійно будує повну словозмінну парадигму. [...]
> > Станом на сьогодні в електронному словнику системні помилки відсутні взагалі, але трапляються поодинокі несистемні. Коли в словнику загалом понад п'ять мільйонів слів і знайдено 10-15 помилок, то який це відсоток? Але щодалі, то важче й важче знаходити помилки (''сміється'').
> > <sub>[Словниковий запас](http://www.umoloda.kiev.ua/number/934/285/33992/) від Лілії Бондарчук в «Україна молода» від 13 червня 2007 року</sub>

До речі, на [Вікіпедія:Іменування статей/Географічні об'єкти](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%86%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%BE%D0%B1%27%D1%94%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8) у разі розбіжностей радять розбиратись і слідувати в першу чергу сучасному українському правопису.